# Angular 9 search and update element in the markup stored in a database

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have an Angular application where it shall be possible to customize some "screens". It shall be possible to upload a HTML file, that HTML file contains some elements that shall be updated on the fly. So together with that HTML file the user also needs to upload a configuration file that contains some references between element ids in the HTML file, and some id for some values that will be request from an API.

Now my problem is how can I do that using Angular?

If it was jQuery I would do something like this:

```
$('#[element_Id_From_config_file]').value([the_value_returned_from_API_Request]);
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('element_Id_From_config_file').value=the_value_returned_from_API_Request`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I was hopping that I could do it in an more angular way?